# Mat datepicker doesn't emit event after parse

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I am using for my datepicker MAT_DATE_FORMATS provider a custom date format which parses the input value to 'DD/MM/YYYY'.

The problem that I have is that there are no events after the parse is done so I can't know the parsed value in my ts file.

So what's happening is that I for example write "18/02/1993aaaa" and change, ngModelChange, dateChange and dateInput events emitters are emitting that value "18/02/1993aaaa" but what you are visually seeing is that the value is parsed to "18/02/1993".

Is there anyway to get that value after is parsed?

```
<input #dateInput [attr.placeholder]="placeholder" type="text" [matDatepicker]="myDatepicker" [min]="min"
      [max]="max" (change)="onChange($event.target.value)" (keyup)="onKeyup($event)" (blur)="onBlur($event)"
      (dateInput)="onChange($event)" (dateChange)="onChange($event)" [(ngModel)]="value" />
<div class="c-input__trigger">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle [for]="myDatepicker" disableRipple>
    <c-gen-icon matDatepickerToggleIcon [icon]="icons.CALENDAR" filled="true" [theme]="themes.ACCENT"></c-gen-icon>
  </mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #myDatepicker></mat-datepicker>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add some relevant code? Are you using the `changes` event by the DatePicker? https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/api

Comment: You can block user to type on the datepicker! Like you know `aaaa` is not a valid number or a valid date

Comment: I want to allow to write the date manually. The parser works good, the problem is to get the value when is parsed

Comment: @JacopoSciampi there is no change event by DatePicker but dateChange and dateInput. change event emitter is the one from the input